# hosted build visual studio online

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, azure-devops

I'm trying to run a hosted build online with VSO.
Projects and website in the solution build fine locally, and the build definition is set to : 'Copy build output to the following source control folder(this folder will be created if it does not exist)' which is $/xxx.CoreProject.V2/Drops.

When I run the build, I get the following multiple build errors:

d:\a\src\TFS\xxxxxx\xxxxx.metaproj: Unable to copy file "d:\a\bin\xxxxxx.pdb" to "WebsiteProjects\xxxxxx\Bin\xxxx.pdb". Access to the path 'WebsiteProjects\xxxxx\Bin\xxxxxx.pdb' is denied.

This happens on .xml,.pdb and some dll's.

As the drop folder is created by VSO in the hosted source control environment, can anyone tell me why it's giving access denied errors?

Thanks

Comment: Web site or web application?

Answer (score 0):

If you have binaries or other files under source control in the bin folder then they will be tried in a test only state. You should not invites in source control any files that are built during the build process.